# Heroku crash: log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

While migrating an Heroku app from Bamboo to Cedar, I get this unexpected error:

```
app[web.1]: Exiting
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `initialize'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:247:in `new'
app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:247:in `block in build_app'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:243:in `build_app'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:243:in `reverse_each'
app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:     from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
app[web.1]:     from script/rails:6:in `require'
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Most important line:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.0.19/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:8:in `size': No such file or directory - log/production.log (Errno::ENOENT)

- I have no `production.log` in my source code.
- My `config/environments/production.rb` says `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`.
- I use `logger.debug` at a few dozens places in my source code.

Heroku does not even allow writing to filesystem, so I don't know where that comes from.
Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the line `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` from file `config/environments/production.rb`, and that solved the problem.

The server is now starting successfully.